# iPhone 6s & 6s plus BLE Background Connection Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Iphone 6s and 6s plus device bluetooth doesn't connect with my external device in background mode.. And it works well with other devices such as 5s, 6 & 6 plus.

Here I am trying to connect with specific external device & having problem only with 6s & 6s plus device.

Is there any BLE specific update in these devices.? Thanks